# Sharing object between forms and a background thread worker in a windows form app

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have the following situation.

Multiple forms that display information stored in a shared object. A background worker thread that is constantly updating the shared object.

I thought about having the shared object be something like a singleton but I am worried about the multi threading concerns.

What is the best way to solve this kind of problem?

I was asked what is the problem but I thought I covered that but I will try to add more detail.

Ok I have one lets say an object like this

```
public class Connections
{
public List<User> Users {get;set;}
public List<Computer> Computers {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have 2 different forms that are open at the same time.  One form is for displaying the Users, the other is for displaying the Computers.

Next I have a background thread that is populating the Users and Computers.

How can I share the data that the background thread is building with multiple forms?

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: What's the “shared object”? A forms control? `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` will already marshal to the UI thread; is that what you're doing?

Comment: I tried to add more detail to the problem.  And no I was not doing anything with BackgroundWork, I am actually not sure what that does (Going to go look that up now)

Answer (score 0):

Any data shared between the background thread and the UI thread needs to be protected by locks.  That is, you need to pick an object to synchronize on (possibly the "main object" that's being shared, if there is one), and anytime you modify or read a member variable from that object, you need to first lock on it.

Alternatively, you could use Control.Invoke() from the background thread anytime you need to update data so that only the UI thread will actually modify the shared object, making it effectively no longer shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean way to solve this problem is by using Tasks (System.Threading.Tasks) instead of a BackgroundWorker. Pass in a SyncronizationContext created on a UI thread and the framework does all the locking work for you.